# Making code elegant, clean and optimized

Tags: c

I have some piece of code that I already optimized, however I found that there is an edge case that I should handle and I am unable to make it elegant.

```
char* data = get_data_from_queue(data);
Album album;
get_album(data, &album);
if (get_album_vals(album) <= 0) {
    printf("Album doesn't exist, will try to create it");
    return should_create_album(album);
}
do_stuff_with_data(&data);
```

Now, when I don't find album vals, under certain conditions (< 0.01%), it may be a golden album.
If it is a golden album, under certain conditions (<0.01%), it may need a second chance.

This is the modified code that should keep same behavior, apart from the second chance for golden album:

```
char* data = get_data_from_queue(data);
Album album;
get_album(data, &album);
if (get_album_vals(album) <= 0) {
    int is_golden_album = 0;
    ret = should_create_album(album);
    if (!ret && album_might_be_golden(album)) {
        GoldenAlbum golden_album;
        if (get_golden_album(data, &golden_album)
        {
            ret = should_create_album(golden_album);
        } else {
            is_golden_album = 1;
        }
    }
    if (is_golden_album > 0)
    {
        return ret;
    }
}
do_stuff_with_data(&data);
```

However the new code is awful and I am not sure how to make it more elegant and optimized and I have spent way too much time on this.

Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Site where we review actual working code from your project and provide suggestions on how to improve that code. There are 2 problems with the question that could make it off-topic for this site. Unlike stack overflow we need more code to be able to analyze how the code can be improved. Functions names like `do_stuff_with_data()` seem to indicate this is -topic.not the real code. If that is the real name of the function than we need to see the entire `do_stuff_with_data()` function. The code you have posted is not a complete function and that makes it off

Answer (score 3):

The inelegance lies in the way you're storing your data.  You haven't normalized it, so you have to check multiple places for what should be the same information.

Why are golden albums in a different list?  The fact that you need to check *that* list too, should be an indication that those two lists should be the same.  Just like the artists, producers, and other information about the album, whether or not it's golden (and indeed, how many times, if I understand golden album status correctly) is an attribute of the data.

You don't spend much time justifying why `GoldenAlbum` and `Album` are different types. Without knowing much about the data you're modeling, it's hard to be sure exactly what your data attempts to describe.  So maybe I'm misunderstanding what 'golden' means for an 'album'.  But if you have only one `Album` object and it has a `is_golden` attribute, you can avoid continuing to implement checks for both types of album in any code that interacts with the data by album name.